# UIMenuController

Tags: objective-c, uimenucontroller

I wish to display 2 or more UIMenuControllers on the singleTap event. I can display one menuItem but when I try to display 2  of them only the last(latest) one is being displayed.

Firstly, is it even possible to display 2 or more UIMenuControllers on the same View??
Secondly, if yes, could someone please show me where to go on from displaying one menu to 2.

I am using this method to label parts of the screen that activate the menu on singleTap.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question for further reference if anyone else is looking for the same query.
You can have only one UIMenuController at a time. Its a shared menuController hence.
For further reference:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html